# Browse Nokia 2700 Classic SMS messages on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, mobile-phone, sms

The SMS Inbox on my Nokia 2700 Classic is overflowing! (>3000). I would like to be able to browse them and quickly select which messages to delete. Is there a way to do this on a Mac?